# Meteor.js – $or mongodb query based on Session variables

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm building a page on a meteor site that lists the documents of a collection. The collection is stored in a variable called Tools and has a field named "categories". At the top of this page, I want to have buttons that correspond to the categories; when the button is active, the documents of that category show up. When a button is not active, the documents of that category do not show up.

The thing that's throwing me is that I want to set it up so that you can select multiple categories at once.

To hard code the mongodb query to return multiple category would be something like:

```
Tools.find(
  { $or: 
    [
      { category: 'tech' },
      { category: 'creative' } 
    ] 
  }
);
```

**But I can't figure out how to write this query such that it updates according to Session variables.**

As for the Session variables themselves, would it be better to have a boolean variable for each category? As in...

```
Session.set('tech', true);
Session.set('creative', false);
//etc...
```

Or would it be better to store them in an array? As in...

```
Session.set('categories', ['tech', 'creative']);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of categories seems like it would be much easier to manage:

```
Session.set('categories', ['tech', 'creative']);
```

Then you can do this:

```
Tools.find({category: {$in: Session.get('categories')}});
```

Comment: Killed it! Thank you. Didn't know about the $in operator.